# Can I have a condition inside of a where or a filter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have a **dataframe** with many columns, and to explain the situation, let's say, there is a **column with letters in it from a-z**. I also have a **list**, which includes some **specific letters**.

```
val testerList = List("a","k")
```

The dataframe has to be filtered, to only include entries with the specified letters in the list. This is very straightforward:

```
val resultDF = df.where($"column".isin(testerList:_*)))
```

So the problem is, that the list is given to this function as a parameter, and it can be an empty list, which situation could be solved like this (resultDF is defined here as an empty dataframe):

```
if (!(testerList.isEmpty)) {
 resultDF = df.where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
                  .where($"column".isin(testerList:_*)))
} else {
  resultDF = df.where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
}
```

Is there a way to make this in a more simple way, something like this:

```
val resultDF = df.where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
                      .where((!(testerList.isEmpty)) && $"column".isin(testerList:_*)))
```

This one throws an error though:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Boolean
                                    .where( (!(testerList.isEmpty)) && (($"agent_account_homepage").isin(testerList:_*)))
                                                                                                        ^
```

So, thanks a lot for any kind of ideas for a solution!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I use now, use sql code inside the where clause:

```
var testerList = s""""""
var cond = testerList.isEmpty().toString
testerList = if (cond == "true") "''" else testerList

val resultDF= df.where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
                .where("('"+cond+"' = 'true') or (agent_account_homepage in ("+testerList+"))")
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
val filtered1 = df.where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
val resultDF = if (testerList.isEmpty) 
  filtered1 
else 
  filtered1.where($"column".isin(testerList:_*))
```

Or if you don't want `filtered1` to be available below and perhaps unintentionally used, it can be declared inside a block initializing `resultDF`:

```
val resultDF = {
  val filtered1 = df.where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
  if (testerList.isEmpty) filtered1 else filtered1.where($"column".isin(testerList:_*))
}
```

or if you change the order

```
val resultDF = (if (testerList.isEmpty) 
  df
else 
  df.where($"column".isin(testerList:_*))
).where(some other stuff has to be filtered away)
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially what **Spark** expects to receive in `where` is plain object `Column`. This means that you can extract all your complicated *where* logic to separate function:

```
def testerFilter(testerList: List[String]): Column = testerList match {
   //of course, you have to replace ??? with real conditions
   //just apend them by joining with "and"
    case Nil => $"column".isNotNull and ??? 
    case tl => $"column".isin(tl: _*) and ???
}
```

And then you just use it like:

```
df.where(testerFilter(testerList))
```